# get ajax error message

Tags: jquery

The error I get is this:

```
POST http://mypage.local/page1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

That webpage is unavailable - but that's okay. What I want to be able to do is display that error (or something similar to that error) on the page so the user can see the error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
     ...
     // If there's an error...
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         // Record the error
         $('#a-error').show().text(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(error);
          console.log(tasks);
      }
```

This doesn't work though. `xhr.responseText` is empty. And the `error` object I see in console.log doesn't seem to have any error messages.

What should I do?

Comment: what does `console.log(status);` give you?

Comment: status just returns: `error`

Comment: Try this one: `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));` you will get the exact error in string. First and third parameters are JSON encoded.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));` gives me `""`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You seem to log the error object. Did you try inspecting the object and/or use `console.dir`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try different format [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
     var jqxhr =$.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: url,
          data: JSON.stringify(data)
       })
        .done(function() {
        alert( "success" );
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
      })
      .always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
      });
```

where `fail()` will called for the error conditions.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you may want to have a look at statusCode property of [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```